# How to output pr_info() information with linux kernel startup

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

When the kernel boots, messages will be output to the serial port.

If `printk("Information")` is called, the "Information" will be displayed by the serial port.

I want to display all the `pr_info（“”)` information in Linux Kernel by serial port. How to build the kernel?

Answer (score 2):

Increase the loglevel by either "loglevel=x" or "ignore_loglevel".

Check this doc for details: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt